# Sort by Object within Object in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, sorting

I have a `persons` list and I sort it by the column in `sortColumn`.

```js
const persons = [{
    name: "alireza",
    family: "seif",
    other: {
      age: 28,
      rate: 30
    }
  },
  {
    name: "sara",
    family: "niki",
    other: {
      age: 15,
      rate: 15
    }
  },
  {
    name: "fateme",
    family: "azizy",
    other: {
      age: 27,
      rate: 35
    }
  }
];
const sortColumn = {
  path: "name",
  order: "asc"
};
persons.sort((person1, person2) =>
  person1[sortColumn.path] > person2[sortColumn.path] ?
  sortColumn.order === "asc" ?
  1 :
  -1 :
  person2[sortColumn.path] > person1[sortColumn.path] ?
  sortColumn.order === "asc" ?
  -1 :
  1 :
  0
);
console.log(persons);
```

If `sortColumn.path` is `"name"` and `order` is `"asc"` (or `"desc"`), the `sort` function works correctly. But how can I sort by `"other.age"`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take a functin which return a sort function, depending on the sort order.

This sorting function uses another function for getting a value from an object by reducing the splitted path to the value.

```js
const
    sortBy = ({ order = 'asc', path }) => order === 'asc'
        ? (a, b) => ((a, b) => a > b || -(a < b))(getValue(a, path), getValue(b, path))
        : (a, b) => ((a, b) => b > a || -(b < a))(getValue(a, path), getValue(b, path)),
    getValue = (object, keys) => keys.split('.').reduce((o, k) => o[k], object),
    persons = [{ name: "sara", family: "niki", other: { age: 15, rate: 15 } }, { name: "alireza", family: "seif", other: { age: 28, rate: 30 } }, { name: "fateme", family: "azizy", other: { age: 27, rate: 35 } }];

console.log(persons.sort(sortBy({ path: "name", order: "asc" })));
console.log(persons.sort(sortBy({ path: "other.rate", order: "desc" })));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: thank you. in code `console.log(persons.sort(sortBy({ path: "name", order: "asc" })));` must sort [{name:'alireza'...},{name:'fateme'...},{name:'sara'..}}

Comment: @A.R.SEIF, i see the result in the wanted order.

Comment: thank you.i am copy code in console browser .and result not equals.thanks

Comment: you may have a problem with console, bcause this is sometimes async to the data. for comparing take `JSON.stringify` and check against.

Comment: some more to read: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23392111/console-log-async-or-sync

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do sort by that deep property `age`, you can't use `sortColumn` exactly as you have... Instead, one option is to modify it by making it an array of properties, like so:

```
sortColumn = { path:["other","age"], order:"asc" }
```

This way, you'd also have to modify the sort function - as seen in the example below:

```js
const persons = [
  {name:"alireza",family:"seif",other:{age:28,rate:30}},
  {name:"fateme",family:"azizy",other:{age:27,rate:35}},
  {name:"sara",family:"niki",other:{age:15,rate:15}}
]

const sortColumn = { path:["other","age"], order:"asc" }

persons.sort((person1, person2) =>
  person1[sortColumn.path[0]][sortColumn.path[1]] > person2[sortColumn.path[0]][sortColumn.path[1]] 
    ? sortColumn.order === "asc"
      ? 1
      : -1
    : person2[sortColumn.path[0]][sortColumn.path[1]]  > person1[sortColumn.path[0]][sortColumn.path[1]] 
    ? sortColumn.order === "asc"
      ? -1
      : 1
    : 0
);

console.log(persons)
```

**However**, this approach doesn't work to sort by `"name"` since this sort function sorts your data by some piece of data that is two-layers deep (inside `"other"`, then `"age"`). Here's a modification you can make to the sort function which lets you sort by any properties, any number of layers deep into your data:

```js
const persons = [
  {name:"alireza",family:"seif",other:{age:28,rate:30}},
  {name:"fateme",family:"azizy",other:{age:27,rate:35}},
  {name:"sara",family:"niki",other:{age:15,rate:15}}
]

const sortColumn = { path:["name"], order:"asc" }

persons.sort((person1, person2) => {
  // get array of paths
  const sortPaths = sortColumn.path;

  // get values to sort by
  const val1 = sortPaths.reduce((acc, path) => {
    if (acc[path]) return acc[path]
    else alert(`can't find prop ${path} in person1`);
  }, person1)
  const val2 = sortPaths.reduce((acc, path) => {
    if (acc[path]) return acc[path]
    else alert(`can't find prop ${path} in person2`);
  }, person2)

  return val1 > val2 
    ? sortColumn.order === "asc"
      ? 1
      : -1
    : val2  > val1 
    ? sortColumn.order === "asc"
      ? -1
      : 1
    : 0
});

console.log(persons)
```

```html
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59792589/sort-object-in-object-by-javascript/59792918#
```

As you can see in this second snippet, you can now search by a shallow property `"name"` by using `path: ["name"]`, but if you want to sort by a deep value, just add both properties to the path array like this: `path: ["other", "age"]`

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

The main thing to do is to make your code expect 'path' be a function that selects a property's value, instead of a string pointing to a property name.  That way it's much more flexible.

```
const sortColumn = {
    path: p => p.other.age,
    order: 'desc'
};
```

However, if 'persons' is not the only object you'd like to do this with, you can further abstract such a function for general use with any array, such as this:

```
function sorter (array, path, order) {

  array.sort((a,b) => {

    let result = 
      path(a) > path(b) ? 1
      : path(a) < path(b) ? -1
      : 0;

    if (order === "desc")
      result = -result;

    return result;

  });

}
```

Use it like this:

```
sorter(persons, p => p.other.age, 'desc');
```

Expand and run the snippet below to see it in action:

```js
function sorter (array, path, order) {

  array.sort((a,b) => {

    let result = 
      path(a) > path(b) ? 1
      : path(a) < path(b) ? -1
      : 0;

    if (order === "desc")
      result = -result;

    return result;

  });
  
}

const persons = [
      {name: "alireza", family: "seif", other: {age: 28, rate: 30}},
      {name: "sara", family: "niki", other: {age: 15, rate: 15}},
      {name: "fateme", family: "azizy", other: {age: 27, rate: 35}}
];

// convenience function
let sortAndLog = (array, path, order) => {
    sorter(array, path, order);
    console.log(array.map(path));
}
sortAndLog(persons, p => p.name, "asc");
sortAndLog(persons, p => p.name, "desc");
sortAndLog(persons, p => p.other.age, "asc");
sortAndLog(persons, p => p.other.age, "desc");
```